# How to store special symbol(+) in database using java?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have a requirement to store the phone number with country code like +919025645765 into the database. But when i'm trying to store the number it stores only 919025645765 only.

I'm doing this using spring with hibernate..

Please help me..
This is my method in controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/signup",method = RequestMethod.POST)
        @ResponseBody() 
        public User processSignUp(@RequestBody SignUpForm signUpForm, HttpServletRequest request)
        {
              User newUser=new User();

             newUser.setFirstName(signUpForm.getFirstname());
             newUser.setPhoneNumber(signUpForm.getMobilenumber());//here mobile number is +919025645765
             userServices.saveUser(newUser);//here we are sending new user to DAOImpl class where data is stored

    }
```

My DaoImpl is:

```
@Override
    public void saveUser(User newUser) {


        try{
                sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(newUser);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

Here data firstname and phone number is storing in db but it appears like 919025645765 this only.. But i need to store +919025645765 like this.

and my pojo class like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User implements  Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1522690839402700573L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="UserID")
    private long userID; 

    @Column(name = "FirstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="PhoneNumber")
    private String phoneNumber;

}
```

Comment: What datatype is the phone number? Can you show some code?

Comment: most special characters, except for period, are disallowed in spring dbs.

Comment: i posted my sample code.. please check it once..

Answer (score 1):

If you must store the "+" then you will need to store the phone number as a String. e.g your pojo could look like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "people",
class Person {

   @Column(nullable = false)
   private String phoneNumber;
}
```